# RxSwift - Class property's binding

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, rx-swift

I have an question about binding:
I have an array of objects of my custom class: Array. Every object can be updated (change his properties value) in bg.
Also I have separated Controller, which take and store one object from list as variable and can update it (object still the same, so in list it will be updated too)

Is there any way to bind all object.property -> UILabels on Controller in way, when property changes automatically call label update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there are multiple ways how to do it, but from your description I would use some kind of subject (because u said there will be changes in background so you will probably need hot observable )....For example Variable or PublishSubject. So you can crate

```
let myArrayStream: Variable<[MyObject]> = Variable([])
```

you can pass this variable as dependency to wherever you want, on one side you can subscribe to it, on the other side you can update it's value.

Comment: And if I need to subscribe to one object from array, I should use `Variable<MyObject>`? 
When passing one element from array, something like this: `vcProperty: Variable<MyObject> = array.value[index]`?
So if I will change vcProperty.prop, both subscribers (for vcProperty and array) will be notified about this event, right?